# I have to plot an hypotrocoid using functions. My code is not showing anything in the plots

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I said in the title, when I run my program, nothing is shown in the plots. I'm not sure if my problem comes from the courbeFerme function or the hypotrochoid function. Been working on this all morning trying to fix it but with no results. Thank you so much in advance for the answers.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=0
def courbeFerme(R,r):
    #Cette fonction assure qu'on a une courbe fermé
    m=0
    n=(r/(R-r))*m
    if (R in range(0,1000)) and (r in range(0,1000)):
        while ((r/(R-r))*m).is_integer()==0: #Tant que n n'est pas un entier refaire boucle
            m+=1
            n=(r/(R-r))*m           
        return n


def hypotrochoide(R,r,d,phi0=0,color='k'):  #Tracer hypotrochoide
    
    angle=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi*courbeFerme(R,r),2000) 
    
    phi0=np.radians(float(phi0)) #angle de depart dans le petit cercle
    
    #les equations de hypotrochoide
    x=(R-r)*np.cos(angle)+d*np.cos(-((R-r)/r)*angle+phi0)
    y=(R-r)*np.sin(angle)+d*np.sin(-((R-r)/r)*angle+phi0)
    
    #graph
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.plot(x,y,color)
    plt.show()
    
    return

hypotrochoide(264,110,80,0,'midnightblue')
hypotrochoide(252,105,80,20,'royalblue')
hypotrochoide(240,100,80,40,'yellowgreen')
hypotrochoide(252,105,80,60,'royalblue')
hypotrochoide(60,35,20,0,'olive')
hypotrochoide(70,15,10,0,'midnightblue')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the condition of your while clause. You never go inside your while loop because your condition is always true : `m==0` so `((r/(R-r))*m)==0` so `((r/(R-r))*m).is_integer() is True`

To have the result that you want, you need to change the value m to 1 at the beginning of your function `courbeFerme`